# how to solve Invalid constant value.dart erreur

Tags: flutter

i wanna show a message i have specific condition else another one
so i have choose the visibility widget . my problem is that it shows error on !isValidEmail   . isValidEmail   is a bool variable

> Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)

```
 Visibility(
            visible: (!isValidEmail && isDouleEmail),
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: !isValidEmail 
                  ? Text(
                      "Mail incorrect",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      " not found found ",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use `const` when you pass variable in

use it like this  (remove the const in Padding widget)

```
 Visibility(
            visible: (!isValidEmail && isDouleEmail),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: !isValidEmail 
                  ? Text(
                      "Mail incorrect",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    )
                  : Text(
                      " not found found ",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Padding widget is not a constant because its child is changing according to `isValidEmail` value. However, you declare it as a constant.

Remove `const` in `child: const Padding(`